get scroll position of IG body region
I have page with different IG regions
first IG is saving Automatic every time interval using :
apex.region("PENDINGORDERS").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").invoke("save");
this reset the paganing of the region, I need to go to same position where the scrollbar was, so I've tried
savepos = $(window).scrollTop();
but this gets thw window scrollbar
so tried this
savepos = $("#PENDINGORDERS").scrollTop();
but it always gets 0
what i'm missing here

Consider using setSelectedRecords and marking the row you want to be visible/focused. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aexjs/interactiveGrid.html#setSelectedRecords for more info.

Just invoking the save action won't reset the pagination.
